# Powershell - Copy file to another folder while keeping folder structure

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a large folder with many sub directories and files. I am only interested to copy specific files from that large folder to a new folder along with the folder structure. I am using Powershell to achieve this goal. Right now I am interested to copy single file with folder structure. I will use a loop later on top of it once its done.

I can achieve this via coding in python or java but I have to run it on a remote server where I only have access to Powershell. I don't have much experience with Powershell.

I tried searching docs and internet and came up with the following two commands :

```
1) Copy-Item -Path LargeFolder\folder1\sub-folder1\file1.txt -Destination NewFolder\ -Recurse
2) Get-ChildItem -Path LargeFolder\folder1\sub-folder1\file1.txt | Copy-Item -Destination NewFolder\ -Recurse -Container
```

Both command copies only the `file1.txt` to the `NewFolder` without folder structure.

**Output of both commands :**

```
NewFolder
 |- file1.txt
```

**Expected Output :**

```
NewFolder
  |-folder1
    |-sub-folder1
      |-file1.txt

//or even this I don't mind an extra root folder
NewFolder
  |-LargeFolder
    |-folder1
      |-sub-folder1
        |-file1.txt
```

I am a bit lost here. How can I also retain the folder structure ?

Comment: You have to copy each of the folders that contain the files you want to copy, then the files you want to copy in the folder you copied, you can simplify this by having a function that is recursive.

Comment: Do you mean manually ?

Comment: No;  I mean with a PowreShell script.  **I am telling you want the logic would have to be.**  The logic is the most important part of programming.  Anyone can figure out the syntax of a language.

Comment: As I mentioned I am not experienced with powershell. If it were python I would have created folders from the string `"LargeFolder\folder1\sub-folder1\file1.txt"` and then copy the file. I am not sure how to do it here. Can you provide some code samples ?

Comment: You don't need Powershell for this at all on Windows. Just use RoboCopy that has been in Windows OS for years now, purpose-built for this use case using its mirror option. As for this [As I mentioned I am not experienced with powershell. If it were python I would have created folders from the string], it's done the same way using the New-Item cmdlet.to create them in advance, or use the -Force parameter to create if it does not exist. All this is in the Powershell help files and in videos you can search for on Youtube.

Comment: As for this ...[I am not experienced with powershell], that is all well and good, all were here at some point. Yet, that really means you should spend the time getting up to speed on the topic before diving in, as you can really harm/destroy your system or enterprise especially when using destructive commands. ['PowerShell beginning'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell+beginning%27). Read this book 'Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the subfolder structure before you can copy the file to it:

```
$Destination = 'NewFolder'
$FileToCopy = 'LargeFolder\folder1\sub-folder1\file1.txt'

Get-Item $fileToCopy | Copy-Item -Destination {
    $DestPath = Join-Path $Destination (( $_.DirectoryName -Split 'LargeFolder' )[-1] )
    If ( ! ( Test-Path )) { mkdir $DestPath | out-null }
    $DestPath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Robocopy (with or without PowerShell involved at all) and or Copy-Item out of the box and all you need is in the help files:

> ['PowerShell using robocopy'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell%20using%20robocopy%27&t=h_&ia=web)
>
> Youtube - ['PowerShell copy-item'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell%20using%20robocopy%27)

```
Robocopy /?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wednesday, 26 August, 2020 08:40:06
              Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").

::
:: Copy options :
::
                 /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
                 /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
             /LEV:n :: only copy the top n LEVels of the source directory tree.

                 /Z :: copy files in restartable mode.
                 /B :: copy files in Backup mode.
                /ZB :: use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.
                 /J :: copy using unbuffered I/O (recommended for large files).
            /EFSRAW :: copy all encrypted files in EFS RAW mode.

  /COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
                       (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps, X=Skip alt data streams).
                       (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

 
               /SEC :: copy files with SECurity (equivalent to /COPY:DATS).
           /COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info (equivalent to /COPY:DATSOU).
            /NOCOPY :: COPY NO file info (useful with /PURGE).
            /SECFIX :: FIX file SECurity on all files, even skipped files.
            /TIMFIX :: FIX file TIMes on all files, even skipped files.

             /PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
               /MIR :: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).
 ...
```

> Youtube ['PowerShell copy-item'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27PowerShell%20copy-item%27)

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Copy-Item).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Copy-Item).Parameters.Keys
# Results
<#
Path
LiteralPath
Destination
Container
Force
Filter
Include
Exclude
Recurse
PassThru
Credential
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
InformationAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
InformationVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
WhatIf
Confirm
UseTransaction
FromSession
ToSession
#>
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Examples
# Results
<#
Copy-Item "C:\Wabash\Logfiles\mar1604.log.txt" -Destination "C:\Presentation"
Copy-Item "C:\Logfiles" -Destination "C:\Drawings" -Recurse
Copy-Item C:\Logfiles -Destination C:\Drawings\Logs -Recurse
Copy-Item "\\Server01\Share\Get-Widget.ps1" -Destination "\\Server12\ScriptArchive\Get-Widget.ps1.txt"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "D:\Folder001\test.log" -Destination "C:\Folder001_Copy\" -ToSession $Session
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server02" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "D:\Folder002\" -Destination "C:\Folder002_Copy\" -ToSession $Session
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server04" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "D:\Folder003\" -Destination "C:\Folder003_Copy\" -ToSession $Session -Recurse
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server04" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "D:\Folder004\scriptingexample.ps1" -Destination "C:\Folder004_Copy\scriptingexample_copy.ps1" -ToSession $Session
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "C:\MyRemoteData\test.log" -Destination "D:\MyLocalData\" -FromSession $Session
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "C:\MyRemoteData\scripts" -Destination "D:\MyLocalData\" -FromSession $Session
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
 Copy-Item "C:\MyRemoteData\scripts" -Destination "D:\MyLocalData\scripts" -FromSession $Session
#>
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Full
Get-help -Name Copy-Item -Online
```